# "The import is never used" en Java con VSCode

Tags: java, array

estoy empezando a programar en este IDE pero me he encontrado con el problema a la hora de importar un java.util. Me menciona el error sobre este código

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] numeros = {1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(numeros[0]);
    }
}
```

En el import java.util.Arrays aparece: *The import java.util.Arrays is never used*

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error para que me pueda dejar utilizar las herramientas sin problemas?
Gracias!

Comment: Removiendo el import que no estás utilizando.

Comment: No es un error, es un "aviso" (warning)